# Get difference between set epoch time and now in seconds

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I have a time in epoch time. This time is always in the future.

I would like to figure out how to take this epoch time and figure out the seconds between *now* and the supplied *epoch time* in Objective-C (iOS), but I am not entirely sure how to go about this.

I have tried `NSTimeInterval interval = [futureTime timeIntervalSinceNow];` but I am not sure what to do with `interval`

Much appreciated.

Comment: When you say epoch time, you mean number of seconds since 1st January 1970 12:00AM, GMT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval secondsSinceUnixEpoch = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
```

This will calculate the number of seconds between "now" and January 1, 1970 (Unix Epoch).

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

`interval` is the number of seconds between now and `futureTime`

Comment: OK, I have figured out that I am creating the wrong NSDate (from epoch time): `[[[timeArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"epochTime"] intValue];`. If I NSLog the object directly, and do not grab the intValue, it outputs the correct number (as a string). However, as soon as I try and convert it to an intValue, the number doesn't correspond. Do I need to use another type?

Comment: @Canada Dev what type of object is returned by `objectForKey:@"epochTime"`?

Comment: raw XML output is `epochTime="1293138561491"`. I use NSXMLParser to parse it. I place the attributeDict objects into an NSMutableArray, which outputs it in the console as `epochTime = 1293163536472;` (when outputting the entire array)